# Grouping Strings and Adding into a list

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, string, linq

I have now updated to a Complex Situation now and i am terribly stuck. Kindly Let me know if you can share some light to it.

I No more have this as `List<string>`. It is now a `List<categories>` Which will have the Following properties

```
public class Categories 
    {
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        public string ValueCode { get; set; }
        public string Count { get; set; }           
    }
```

This will have Values like

```
Category1/SubCategory1
cat1/sc1
5

Category1/SubCategory2
cat1/sc2
4

Category 2/Subcategory1
cat2/sc1
5

Category 2/Subcategory2
cat2/sc2
23
```

So, i updated my Existing JobCateogry Clas
and so on.

```
 public class JobCateogry 
    {
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        public string ValueCode { get; set; }
        public string Count { get; set; }
        public List<JobCateogry> SubCategories { get; set; }
    }
```

I tried to Split the string and assign it to the new class in two step first by splitting and then by assiging. 
But i am sure i am doing it the wrong way, because the moment i split,  i loose the count .

```
var lstCategory =  Categories 
                        .Where(i => i.count > 0)
                        .Select(item => item.valueCode.Split('/')                                        
                        .Select(k =>(k)).ToList();

   List<JobCategories> jobcategories = lstCategory
                                      .Select(item => item.Split(QueryStringConstants.CAT_SEPERATOR.ToCharArray()[0]))
                                      .GroupBy(tokens => tokens[0].Trim(), tokens => tokens[1])
                            .Select(g => new JobCategories(g.Key,  g.DisplayName,g.ToList(),)).ToList();
```

Can you please help?

(i need to split by Value code and Show the DisplayName and Count)

*** Old Question *** 
I have a List that has strings something like this

```
"Category1/SubType1"
"Category1/SubType2"
"Category1/SubType3"  
"Category1/SubType4" 
"Category2/SubType1"
"Category2/SubType2"   
"Category2/SubType3" 
"Category2/SubType4"
```

i have a class that has two properties.

```
public string Category { get; set; }
public  List<string> SubCategory{ get; set; }
```

I need to iterate through the list,  and pick all the categories and then add subcategories to them.

I had sorted the list and I was able to achieve the traditional way by doing a for loop by taking the first string and comparing with the rest. 
I was wondering if there is any neater way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Splitting each list item and then grouping by category name should give the desired result:

```
list.Select(item => item.Split('/'))
    .GroupBy(tokens => tokens[0], tokens => tokens[1])
    .Select(g => new TheClass
                     {
                         Category = g.Key,
                         SubCategory = g.ToList()
                     });
```

Comment: The topic creator might want SubCategory to be the collection of tokens[1] - i consider it ambiguous at the moment.  Also, does `g.ToList()` return a `List<string>` or a `List<string[]>`?

Comment: @ItzWarty, `List<string[]>` was not intentional, thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach:

```
var query = from input in inputs
            let split = input.Split('/')
            group split[1] by split[0] into grouping
            select new MyClass
            {
                Category = grouping.Key,
                SubCategory = grouping.ToList()
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ought to work

```
IEnumerable<string> items = GetSomeItems() ;

Widget[] list = items
                .Select( s => s.Split('/') )
                .GroupBy( x => x[0] , x => x[1] )
                .Select( g => new Widget( g.Key , g.ToList() ) )
                .ToArray()
                ;
```

given a class like this:

```
class Widget
{
  public Widget ( string category , IEnumerable<string> subcategories )
  {
    this.Category      = category ;
    this.Subcategories = subcategories.ToArray() ;
  }
  public string Category { get; private set; }
  public string[] Subcategories { get ; private set ; }
}
```